# How to change materials in animation?

Tags: animation

I want to animate the changing of materials my model.

After the first frame I want to around blocks (or just the colors of the blocks) to and from somewhere in the model.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do: [image]

I'm going to import the .blend file into unity. I just want the animation to play over and over again (like a gif).

Comment: I dont really understand what ur asking here.

Comment: completely redid the question >.<

Comment: do you want to make a .gif? or .mp4? or simply have you animation looping inside of blender?

Comment: I want to have the animation loop endlessly when the .blend file is imported into blender

Comment: basically what I want is a 3d gif in the form of a single blender model with the option of having some depth added.

Comment: So you want the 3d cubes moving in 3d in Unity? Thats either rig the cubes and animate in Blender as an action and export FBX or you can also easily make cubes move in Unity by keyframe animating or scripting. Color changing is best done inside Unity using texture that has all the colors and scripting change to UV offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a VideoTexture script, use the script at the bottom of this thread

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?189973-Changing-object-textures-in-game-engine-quot-on-the-fly-quot-(animated-textures)

Comment: hmm might work but would it easily mesh with unity?

Comment: No. Sorry. This is strictly a Blender Game Engine-thing. I think for this type of thing in Unity, you'll have to look for a script/plug-in there.

Comment: You can certainly change colours for each surface on the fly as it were. Just create/allot a different material slot for each cube side or segment  make the changes when required and keyframe them.  Looping would have to be done in Unity I imagine, either that or duplicate the keyframes often enough  for your final product.  If only wanting geometrical shapes as you have in the upper left surface, make those using the normal mesh geometry and colour them accordingly.  I can load up a simple Blender file (which is not on this computer) to demonstrate how to change colouring if you wish.